# Can an argument be passed through the "alias" command?

Tags: command-line, alias

I want to know if i can pass an argument with an alias command.

for example:

```
alias d="dmesg|grep -iw usb|tail -5"
```

Now d will print the last 5 lines. if i want to use d to print a different number of lines, i have to make change in the alias command declaration of d again.

Is there any way i can modify the declaration of alias command so that i don't have to retype the declaration to change the number of lines. Like incorporating passing the number of lines as an argument while declaring alias for d or is there some other method to solve this?

Comment: which shell are you using?

Answer (score 3):

> > Can an argument be passed through the “alias”

No. An alias is a simple string-replace.

Use functions.

```
d(){
   dmesg|grep -iw usb|tail -"$1" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case - yes, you can as exception, because you argument is the last in line:

```
alias d='dmesg | grep -iw usb | tail'
d -5
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Which shell are you using ?
In zsh arguments can be passed something like this -

```
d () {
    dmesg|grep -iw usb|tail -$1
}
```

alias would always just substitute the short string with the long string.